# k-smallest values in array in a sorted order

Tags: python

Given an array of size `n`, the problem is to return first `k` smallest elements, in sorted order.
My idea was to update an QuickSort algorithm , to find first the first `k` element and then recursive update problem to find `k-1` biggest elements. 
Can't find where my mistake is.

```
    def partition(a, left, right):
      pivot = a[left]
      p = left
      q = right
      while(p < q):
        while(a[q] > pivot and p < q):
          q-=1
        while(a[p] <= pivot and p < q):
          p+=1
        a[p] , a[q] = a[q] , a[p]
      a[left],a[p]=a[p],a[left]
      return p


    def kthSmallest(a, left, right, k,c=0):
      if left>=right:
        return a[c:]
      else:
        curr = partition(a, left, right)
        if curr - left == k - 1:
          return kthSmallest(a, left,curr-left-1,k-1,c+1)
        if(curr - left > k - 1):
          return kthSmallest(a, left, curr-1, k,c)
        return kthSmallest(a, curr+1, right, k - (curr - left + 1),c)

temp=[8,5,2,1,6,7,4,9,0]

print(kthSmallest(a,0,len(temp)-1,2))
```

Comment: Please provide the full code and an example of input data for which the code does not output the correct solution

Comment: added drive code

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion doesn't really make sense to me. You should mostly want to follow the normal algorithm for quicksort, you can just avoid sorting the parts of the array you don't care about (the values that are guaranteed to be past the k'th).

Here's how I'd do it. You always recurse on the left partition, and recurse on the right partition if the pivot index `curr` is less than `k`. If `curr` is greater, you can skip the second recursion because we won't need any of those values. I'm splitting the slice out into a non-recursive function, so we don't need to be doing it on every recursive call.

```
def partial_sort(a, left, right, k):
  if left >= right: # base case, do nothing
    return
  curr = partition(a, left, right)
  partial_sort(a, left, curr-1)  # always recurse on the left partition
  if curr < k:     # we only sometimes need to recurse twice
    partial_sort(a, curr+1, right)

def kthSmallest(a, k):
  partial_sort(a, 0, len(a)-1, k)
  return a[:k]
```

I'd also like to note that there's a slightly more efficient algorithm to solve this exact calculation, and it has an implementation in the Python standard library. The `heapq.nsmallest` function uses a binary max-heap to solve this problem *very* elegantly. I strongly suggest [checking it out](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e6a0e804bfad4a5ef03c04d0e3d9a94472966f9a/Lib/heapq.py#L461)!

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to not always sort the left side. We don't need to output the k elements in a sorted fashion.

Comment: They question says they first `n` items *do* need to be sorted. If that's not the case, you only need to recurse on one side or the other, never both. And you might be able to quit early if the pivot after a partition lands on index `k` or `k-1`.

Comment: Ah yes, it's even in the title ... :D

Comment: The elements should be sorted

Answer (score -1):

if I got your problem right you could just use:

```
 min_k_values = np.sort(x, axis = None)[:k]
```

Comment: numpy is a *very* heavy library to bring in to something like this (just using `sorted` would make more sense), and doesn't help the OP figure out what's wrong with their code at all.

Comment: Im sure there is different ways to solve a problem . My approach is to do with O(1) space by changing an QuickSort procedure .

Comment: I'm sorry, I misjudged your question: I  thought you needed a way to find those min values, not that you were writing your own